# Extract All Class names from __init__.py in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the below directory structure in my python project.

```
checks/
  __init__.py
  check_1.py
  check_2.py
main.py
```

Contents inside init.py file are as below where Check1 and Check2 are classes inside check_1.py and check_2.py respectively -

```
__init__.py - 

from .check_1 import Check1
from .check_2 import Check2
```

Contents inside main.py as below -

```
def get_check_class_from_name(check_name: str):
    """
    Checks whether the check is present or not.
    """
    import checks

    checks = dict(
        check_1=checks.CheckDataRelation,
        check_2=checks.CheckDatatype
    )
    try:
        return checks[check_name]
    except KeyError:
        raise ValueError(f"Could not find a check with name '{check_name}'")
```

In main.py, as you see i am creating the dictionary and extracting the check class name based on the check name which is not the best way since tomorrow if new check for e.g. check_3  has to be introduced in **init**.py, again i will modify checks dictionary in main.py like below -

```
checks = dict(
        check_1=checks.CheckDataRelation,
        check_2=checks.CheckDatatype
        check_3 = ?? (this is poor way of hardcoding new checks in this dictionary always)
    )
```

Output - I want to call the function - get_check_class_from_name by passing check_name and it should display the class for that particular check without hardcoding. As mentioned, each time we are adding a check, all this places has to be modified to have an proper implementation.
That’s not best practice in coding.

Requirement - Inside Main.py, i want to get class names for the check name which i pass as argument to get_check_class_from_name

Comment: What is your question? If it is just how to import the __init__, try import checks inside main.py

Comment: What version of python are you using? Do not use all of the python versions and add them into tags

Comment: @LCMa I want to extract all the Class Names from init file i.e. Check1 and Check2 Class

Comment: @12944qwerty Sure, I have removed other versions. I am using 3.7

Comment: check out `inspect.getmembers()`

Comment: @JonSG I have tried but it's not working. Could you please help me by writing the code which works

Comment: you can just do `[obj for name, obj in vars(checks).items() if isinstance(obj, type)]` if you want a list of all the classes you've imported into the `checks` module...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Getting this error - TypeError: vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute

Comment: @Tushaar that's very strange... you shouldn't be getting that error... is there anything special about this module?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga nothing special

Comment: *OH* it's because you've named the `dict` `checks = dict(...)`. That re-assigns the variable to a `dict` rather than the the module object from `import checks`. Remove that line. That's an extremely sloppy bad practice

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I am getting [<class 'checks.check_1.Check1'>,<class 'checks.check_2.Check2'>]. Actually i want to create a dictionary from this which will show {check_1:Check1,check_2:Check2}

Comment: Yes, I know. What is it that you don't have?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I have used this - {obj:name for name, obj in vars(checks).items() if isinstance(obj, type)} but getting output as {<class 'checks.check_1.Check1'>: 'Check1', <class 'checks.check_2.Check2'>: 'Check2'} . What i want is this - {check_1: 'Check1',check_2: 'Check2'}